# Generated table is outside the document

Tags: tables

I am trying to create table

Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|}
\hline
\textbf{Week number} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{A A}}\\ \hline 
\textbf{1} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s \\ when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.\end{tabular}\\ \hline                                       
\textbf{2} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Graphical result is:
[image]

So the table is outside the document. What is wrong?

## Edit:

When I am trying to use the e.g. `p{10cm}`:

So my code now:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{10cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Week number} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{A A}}\\ \hline 
\textbf{1} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s \\ when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.\end{tabular}\\ \hline                                       
\textbf{2} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Basically, in `c`, `l` and `r` columns, text isn't wrapped automatically. You need to use `p` columns where you specify a width, e.g. `p{5cm}`, or have a look at `tabularx` and its `X` columns.

Comment: You do know you have tables inside your table right? The same rule applies for nested tables, no automatic line breaking in `l` columns. But why do you have the inner `tabular` in the first place?

Comment: The table was generated from this page: https://www.tablesgenerator.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\bfseries}c|X|}
    \hline
Week number & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{A A}} \\
    \hline
1
    &   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s  when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.          \\ \hline
2
    &  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You nested tables inside table. Nested tables still has `c` column type, which not break line when it is longer as column in main table. Remove nested table. It make only problems ...

With `tabularx` is simple to achieve what you like to have.